# How can I correctly transform and display strictly increasing values from Influxdb in Grafana?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have some time series in Influxdb which are collected from Linux `/proc` filesystem **every 10 seconds** - for example I/O operations on a hard drive.

These values are by definition strictly increasing, and I want to transform them into I/O operations **per second** (iops) and display them in Grafana.

This is the closest I've come so far:

```
SELECT difference(last("value")) / 10 FROM "disk_write" [WHERE <stuff>] GROUP BY time(10s)
```

I can't find a way to define this query in Grafana with a variable group by time interval.

The problem is, that I can't replace `/ 10` in the `SELECT` block with `/ $interval` (which contains `10s`), which makes this query very slow if I display a huge time window.

How do I define this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [DERIVATIVE()](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/query_language/functions/#derivative).

Something like this:

```
SELECT DERIVATIVE("value") FROM "disk_write" [WHERE <stuff>] GROUP BY time(10s)
```